# Javascript match array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to match multiple arrays and delete similar strings.

```
array1 = ["apple", "cherry", "strawberry"];

array2 = ["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry"];
```

Comment: What do you mean by similar, and from which array are you deleting? Both? Note that you don't have any exact matches in the current arrays, so I'm wondering how you're defining similar.

Comment: Oops, spelling error. array1 is the original so delete matching strings from array2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear so here are two solutions:

Given `["apple", "cherry", "strawberry"]` and `["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry"]` do you want `["apple", "cherry", "strawberry", "vanilla", "chocolate"]`:

```
function combineWithoutDuplicates(array1, array2) {

   var exists = {};
   var unique = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      exists[array1[i]] = true;
      unique.push(array1[i]);
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
      if(!exists[array2[i]]) {
         unique.push(array2[i]);
      }
   }

   return unique;
}
```

Or do you want `["vanilla", "chocolate"]` (removes duplicates from `array2`):

```
function removeDuplicates(array1, array2) {

   var exists = {};
   var withoutDuplicates = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      exists[array1[i]] = true;
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
      if(!exists[array2[i]]) {
         withoutDuplicates.push(array2[i]);
      }
   }

   return withoutDuplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array intersect

http://www.jslab.dk/library/Array.intersect

Comment: An intersection of the above arrays would return `["apple", "cherry", "strawberry"]`. What he wants is `(A ∪ B) - (A ∩ B)`